# How to refresh / reload a Page on click of button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I have two html pages. One is `display.html` and the other is `test.html`. In test.html I have a button:

```
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="button">Go</button>
```

On the other page I am displaying some content. The javascript code of both the pages are in the same JS file.

What I want to know is if I click on the button in `test.html` how can I reload/refresh my other page which is `display.html`?

I am doing something like this

```
$("#btn").on('click',function() {
  window.location = 'display.html';
});
```

This redirects me to that page which is not to what I am trying to do.

**Page 1 where there is button**

```
 <button id="btn" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="button">
         </button>
```

**Page 1 JS code**

```
Imagehandeler
function Imagehandeler() 
{
    $.ajax({
    $("#btn").click(function() {
                localStorage.setItem('doRefresh', 'yes');
});
// ajax callinge here 
}); //ajax closing
} //function closing
```

**Now on page 2 JS**

```
    fullCode();
    function fullCode()
    {
        window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
            var canIRefresh = storage.getItem('doRefresh');
            if(canIRefresh == 'yes'){
                console.log(canIRefresh)
              localStorage.setItem('doRefresh', 'no');
              location.reload();
            }
            });
// Some codes to displaying data
}
```

Now this is what I have thought of

Comment: How are the two pages related? Is one contained in an iframe within the other, for example?

Comment: Not sure I'm interpreting the question correctly, but that's not how websites work. Both pages are separate pages as far as your browser in concerned. So unless one page opens the other, they will not have a reference to each other. You either have to use the server to act as the middleman or have one page open the other so they reference each other.

Comment: what exactly you want?

Comment: @ArshpreetWadehra from one page I want to reload or refresh other page

Comment: @Shilly no the don't have relation

Comment: But given that you can only have one page active at a time, the entire problem seems entirely moot. How are the pages related? What are you expecting reloading a page (which may not even be active at the current point) to do?

Comment: Then no interaction ;). They need to relate to each other in some way, or have the server notify the other in some way. But I would look for a better structure for the pages. If they are unrelated, why does one need to be able to reload the other? Please explain your use case. Since it sounds like they should not be separate pages to begin with. Or that one page has to open the other under some previous condition, before reloading it later.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the two are related one will be on one screen and other would be on other screen when I am clicking button of one page then saving some data in db then want to refresh that page so that it reterive latest data, I am using servlets as my backend and sending and retreving data using `ajax`

Comment: You can use push messages for that. Worst case, have the reloadable page poll the server every x minutes.

Comment: @Shilly I am using servlet as my backend when button clicked that servlet comes into play, so by servlet can I refresh the page

Comment: No idea how to create a socket connection or other push message mechanism in Java. But i'm sure there's some servlet for that somewhere. Maybe tag this question as Java as well.

Comment: @dheerajkumar do not put data to localstorage as value of doRefresh, just put yes. And in second page just add my storage event listener code to your second pages's javascript seciton.

Comment: @mstfyldz I am doing it same as your answer but nothing happening answer

Comment: @dheerajkumar can you debug? is it entering storage event listener? And can you edit your answer with last changes?

Comment: @mstfyldz where you defining that `storage` how will second page know that a button is clicked?

Comment: @dheerajkumar you dont need to define storage. It is window variable and can be accessible from everywhere in page without defining it.

Comment: @mstfyldz hey please chek I have added my code

Comment: @dheerajkumar dont put window event listener in a function. Add it directly to script section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194854/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-mstfyldz).

Comment: @mstfyldz no, nothing happening even console is not happening on second page

Comment: @dheerajkumar how are you opening your A.html To B.html? are they opened in same window? Or are they opened with help of window.open?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for your case but I did not try it before. 
Add a value to localstorage to indicate page refresh. And listen localstorage for value change. When value changes refresh page and restore value to initial state. Like below:

```
localStorage.setItem('doRefresh', 'yes');
```

In Other page listen localstorage:

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { 
    window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) { 
    var canIRefresh = storage.getItem('doRefresh'); 
    console.log(canIRefresh); 
    if(canIRefresh == 'yes'){ 
    console.log(canIRefresh) 

    localStorage.setItem('doRefresh', 'no'); 

    } 
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: hey you saying to I have to pass a dynamic variable in place of `yes`?

Comment: How will I handle that value is changed? and how will I refresh that page?

Comment: Hey look now I have separate js code for two pages on first page I have a function in which there is ajax call so I want to check that data if it is same then needs to re fresh my new page, wait let me edit my post

Comment: hey how would i handle that one page one a button is clicked?

Comment: hey sir  you there ?

Comment: my chat page is not opening please reply here

Comment: @dheerajkumar I have added storage event to dom content loaded event. Can you change and try ?

Comment: yup it worked but it is not the solution which is going to help me because it will work only when both the pages are open is same browser, here my one page is on windows (PC) and other one is in mobile, so local storage will not work

Comment: Yes it will not work in this case. Your only solution will be push notifications. Good lock.

Comment: push notification will work for pages on different browser?

Comment: But that I don't know how to use that I don't think it is simple javascript code, have to use some libraries, some piece of advice will be very helpful

Answer (score -1):

use `window.location.href = path;`

Comment: this will  redirect me to that page which is not I want